# How to prevent intent opening an activity automatically upon receiving push notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, push-notification

I am having a strange issue which is whenever I receive `Push Notification` in my device the `Activity` gets opened automatically. I don't want the `Activity` to show automatically. What I want is to open the `Activity` manually when user clicks on the notification.

Here is my method which will be executed upon receiving the `Push Notification`:-

```
@Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");

            // notifies user
            generateSupportNotification(context, message);

    }
```

This is the method which will be called when push notification receives

```
private void generateSupportNotification(Context context, String message) {

        String classString = "com.pkgName.MainActivity"
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
        notificationIntent.setClassName(context, classString);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        if (isKitKat) {
            NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    getApplicationContext())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("ResHotel")
                    // .setContentText("Welcome!!!")
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                    .setStyle(
                            new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                    .bigText(message))
                    .setFullScreenIntent(resultPendingIntent, true)
                    .setAutoCancel(false);
            boolean isVibrate = new DevicePreferences().getBoolean(context,
                    Constants.VIBRATE, true);
            boolean isSound = new DevicePreferences().getBoolean(context,
                    Constants.SOUND, true);
            if (isVibrate && isSound) {
                notification.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND
                        | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
            } else if (isVibrate && !isSound) {
                notification.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
            } else if (!isVibrate && isSound) {
                notification.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
            }

            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            manager.notify(0, notification.build());
        } else {
            NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    getApplicationContext())
                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("ResHotel")
                     .setContentText(message)
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                    .setStyle(
                            new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                    .bigText(message))
                    .setFullScreenIntent(resultPendingIntent, true)
                    .setAutoCancel(false);

            // notification.setAutoCancel(true);
            boolean isVibrate = new DevicePreferences().getBoolean(context,
                    Constants.VIBRATE, true);
            boolean isSound = new DevicePreferences().getBoolean(context,
                    Constants.SOUND, true);
            if (isVibrate && isSound) {
                notification.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND
                        | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
            } else if (isVibrate && !isSound) {
                notification.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
            } else if (!isVibrate && isSound) {
                notification.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
            }

            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            manager.notify(1, notification.build());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for generate notification

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context ,String name,String number) {
  int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Intent notificationIntent = null;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, "", when);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    String p = "tel:" + number.trim();
    notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse(p));
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "uPosi", "Callback Reminder from "+name, intent);
   // notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;  
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.sound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + context.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;        

    notificationManager.notify(generateUniqueId(), notification);
```

Comment: My code for generating notification is for all versions for Lollipop and its descendents but your code is not compatible with all versions.

Comment: It will not show bigtext message which is of 3-4 line in the notification area. It will just cut the text and show 1 line message

Comment: if message is big then you can use \n .

Comment: that will not make the text in 2 lines. your code will show only 1 line whether message is short or long or contains \n